# Is it right to say "before since"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adverbs, collocation

I wonder if "before since" is right in my sentence. If not, could you please help me improve it?

> This company provides products since 2010. Consequently, there is no record of this product before since.

Comment: As @Ilanysong answers, *before since* is completely wrong. But so is the first sentence in your example usage - idiomatically, native speakers would always say *"**...has been providing** products since 2010"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "before since" can't be used here. "Ever since" is a set construct, so it is considered normative, but "before since" is not.

I would suggest the following:

> This company **has** provid**ed** products since 2010. Consequently, there is no prior record of this product.

Answer (score 3):

No, "before since" makes no sense.

- there is no record before.
- there is no record before that date.

Answer (score 2):

I might go for:

> This company has provided products since 2010. Consequently, there is no record of this product beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> This company has provided products since 2010. Consequently, there is no record of this product before that date.